# Java - Flash socket policy problem

Tags: java, flash, sockets, actionscript, policy

Hello im building a website in flash that has a socket connection to my java server. I got the policy request working but then it closes the socket and connect again. Now my server is waiting on de policy request. Now my question is: is there a way to see if the socket has already received the policy?? Thanks Mkaveli

Answer (score 0):

> Access to socket and XML socket connections is disabled by default, even if the socket you are connecting to is in the same domain as the SWF file. You can permit socket-level access by serving a socket policy file from any of the following locations:
>
> Port 843 (the location of the master policy file)
>
> The same port as the main socket connection
>
> A different port than the main socket connection

[link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c63)

Try to use 843 port to get policy. 
 Oh wait... 2011 year. Ah, pofig.